# How does Apple compresses video using JPEG, JSON, and <canvas>?

Tags: json, video, html5-canvas, jpeg

I found a very nice mechanism to compress videos using JPEG, JSON and canvas.

Apple developed this on his website. The mechanism is [explained here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1GWTMLjqQsQS45FWwqNG9ztQTdGF48hQYpjQHR_d1WsI).

Does anybody know if there is a plugin, programm or something else to create such a thing?

Comment: google css sprite & css3 keyframe

Comment: sry, that's not the same...

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text uses a very similar method to do the animation on [their homepage](http://www.sublimetext.com/). Have a look at the article [Animated GIFs the Hard Way](http://www.sublimetext.com/~jps/animated_gifs_the_hard_way.html)  and the corresponding [Animation Encoder](https://github.com/sublimehq/anim_encoder) script.

The output image is this. It's not unlike Apple's.

[image: anim_enconder output]